# Sorcery and Simple Form implementation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, omniauth, cancan, simple-form, sorcery

long time reader first time user.
I'm putting together my first RoR application and I've isolated everything my app should use down to:-

- Sorcery
- Omniauth
- CanCan
- twitter-bootstrap (converted to sass)

and Simple Forms.

Clean, clear and simple....Not.

Cannot for the life of me integrate (what would seem to be the most simplest of tasks) simple forms with a Sorcery "Login" without getting errors on the 'remember_me' field.

Simple forms doesn't have a simple_form_tag (only simple_form_for) option which would work best on a login form from the sessions controller new method. Instead I have to create a @user instance in that method, but then get errors on the 'remember_me' field "undefined method `remember_me'"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I mean Greatly! Huge thanx in advance :)

```
sessions/new.html.erb

<% provide :title, "Log in" %>
<h1>Log in</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @user, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>

    <%= f.input :email, input_html: { :maxlength => 100 } %>
    <%= f.input :password, input_html: { :maxlength => 20 } %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean %>


    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>

    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) says:

```
form_tag(url_for_options = {}, options = {}, &block)
Starts a form tag that points the action to an url configured with url_for_options just 
like ActionController::Base#url_for. The method for the form defaults to POST.
```

This indicates that `form_tag` is intended to send data directly to another URL, handled by a controller action. Indeed, in the RailsTutorial [signin form](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec%3asignin_form), Michael Hartl uses the `form_for` function instead of `form_tag`.

```
form_for(:session, url: sessions_path)
```

Basically, the idea is that you're sending data to be handled by the controller in some way, instead of writing to the database. Since we don't have a model for user sessions, we have to use the `:session` symbol instead of `@session` and tell the form where (which URL) it should POST the data to.

I suspect, though I'm not sure, that this should work with `simple_form_for` as well. Something like:

```
<%= simple_form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
```

**Update:** I successfully changed the [reference implementation](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed) of the sample app to use `simple_form_for` for creating new user sessions.

That is, of course, assuming that the Sessions controller is handling your login, and that it has a method that responds to POST (probably `create`). That controller action is where you should be handling the Sorcery login.

Here's the Rails documentation for [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for), if you're curious.

Comment: Any ideas on how to use this with omniauth-identity ? I've tried `code`simple_form_for(:user, url: "/auth/identity/register")`/code`

Comment: Any ideas on how to use this with omniauth-identity ? I've tried `simple_form_for(:user, url: "/auth/identity/register")`.  user_controller `def new
    @user = env['omniauth.identity'] || User.new
  end`. model/user.rb `class User < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord`.  This 'seems' to work locally, but not on heroku which errors with `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/auth/identity/register"):`

Comment: If you can, try deleting your first comment since it didn't go through like you expected. I have no idea why that would be working correctly and give you a routing error on Heroku. You should run `rake routes` locally and on Heroku as a debugging step. I really suggest you post this as a new question to give someone the opportunity to earn full reputation if they help you out. It's also nice to upvote the answer you choose if it's helpful.

Comment: thankx jrhorn,  I've made it a question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953672/omniauth-identity-not-working-on-heroku-with-simple-form-for).  FYI, Both routes are identical.  and lastly...hehe  I don't know how to delete my first attempt to comment.  It timed out on me saying I had 5mins max. (or was it because I hit enter trying to do a return )  hehe  can't remember.   Cheers again JR

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do this as well and getting stuck. It seems that this should work but it is causing an error when I submit the login form. Here's what my form looks like:

```
<h1>Log in</h1>

<%= simple_form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, :as => :boolean %>

    <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Login", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Forgot Password?', new_password_reset_path %>
```

Not sure how to make this work. My debug output is showing that the form is trying to send the correct data:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: wGdDEmG91p7RHzWZKLGgMQvKD+XupS1Z557vNDDG6GM=
session: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  email: lee@example.com
  password: test
  remember_me: '1'
commit: Login
action: create
controller: sessions
```

Also, I"m getting this error in the console:

```
gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

But I have `resources :sessions` in my `routes.rb` file.