# omniauth identity not working on heroku with simple_form_for

Tags: heroku, omniauth, simple-form

I'm having trouble with Heroku not playing ball and throwing me this error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/auth/identity/register"):
```

I have the following working in dev.

model/user.rb

```
class User < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord
  has_many :services
```

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def new
  @user = env['omniauth.identity'] || User.new
end
```

users/new.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: "/auth/identity/register" do |f| %><fieldset>
<legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> User</legend>
<%= f.input :name, input_html: { name: "name" } %>
<%= f.input :email, input_html: { name: "email" } %>
<%= f.input :password, input_html: { name: "password" } %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation, input_html: { name: "password_confirmation" } %>
<div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  <%= link_to 'Cancel', users_path, :class => 'btn' %>
</div></fieldset><% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
match "/auth/:service/callback" => 'services#create'
match "/auth/failure" => 'services#failure'
resources :users
```

This all works Perfectly on my machine but Heroku doesn't like it.
environments/development.rb and production.rb are the defaults created with "rails new..." with the following added:-

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
require 'openid/store/filesystem'

provider :identity, fields: [:name, :email],
                    model: User,
                    on_failed_registration: lambda { |env|
                      UsersController.action(:new).call(env)
                    }

# generic openid
provider :open_id, :store => OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp'), :name => 'openid'end
```

Hope this all makes sense and someone has the answer.  Any and all help muchly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Interestingly, if I use a forked version of omniauth-identity "here"[link](https://github.com/slainer68/omniauth-identity/commit/238f38d396e191d85111d9dcd3109314ac4665f6) from Slainer68. I get the same error locally as I do Heroku "No route matches [POST] "/auth/identity/register"):".  So I thought to force the correct version that works locally "gem omniauth-identity, '1.0.0'" so Heroku wouldn't load something different. But alas, this version still works fine locally and barfs on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,  I found the answer, just not sure why this is so though.  Could be another question later if I don't find it here in stackoverflow.

Anyways, I was following this Excellent guide on [www.communityguides.eu](http://www.communityguides.eu/articles/16) and put the omniauth configurations in development.rb and production.rb.  Which made perfect sense as the OpenID::Store paths were different being:-

development.rb
OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('/tmp')

production.rb
OpenID::Store::Filesystem.new('./tmp')

The Answer...
Put the omniauth configurations in initializers/Omniauth.rb

This means I now have to change this file every time I push to Heroku, but Heroku thanks me and allows my app to run nicely.

The question this raises for me (which I'm sure is answered elsewhere).  What is the difference in the load order from Heroku and our Dev environments?  Heroku appears to be loading initializers before the environment configs.  And one more...anyone know a workaround that will save me having to update the Omniauth initializer file every time I want to push to Heroku ?  :)

Thanx for reading and I hope this helps save someone some time.