# Can you use form_for with the sorcery login form instead of form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, sorcery

I'm trying to solve this problem:

[Sorcery and Simple Form implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650075/sorcery-and-simple-form-implementation)

It seems that all I need to do is to be able to use form_for with the sorcery login form instead of `form_tag`. That would enable me to be able to use `simple_form_for`.

How do you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it using a @user variable:

My session controller:

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login, :except => [:destroy]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    if @user = login(params[:user][:username],params[:user][:password],false)
      redirect_back_or_to(root_path, :notice => 'Login successfull.')
    else
      @user = User.new
      flash.now[:error] = "Login failed."; render :action => "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    logout
    redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Logged out!')
  end
end
```

My session view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user,  :html => {:class => 'form-signin'} , :url => {:controller =>   'user_sessions', :action => 'create'} do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :username %>

  <%= f.password_field :password %>  

  <%= f.button :submit, 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```